# Using "in" in "Follow in someone's footsteps"

Tags: prepositions, idioms

Is it necessary to use "in" in this idiom?

> Follow *in* someone's footsteps.

Comment: Yes, you have to use **in**.  Idioms are fixed phrases.  If you change them they aren't the same idiom any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically, "follow someone's footsteps" is fine and will be understood. However, idioms are not about what is grammatically correct, but what people actually use.

What they use can be checked with Google Ngrams. With the query ["follow * footsteps"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=follow+%2A+footsteps&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) you can see the top usage ('follow his footsteps') has a frequency of 1 millionth of a percent:

[image]

The corresponding results for the query ["follow in * footsteps"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=follow+in+%2A+footsteps&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) occur about ten times as often:

[image]

It's interesting to see that in the beginning of the 19th century, 'follow in' wasn't used at all, and only in the last forty years or so, 'follow in' really became more popular.